# Start function of a process A from process B

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it possible to run function in process A from process B?
I want to implement wpf application that will run only as one instance, and if another instance is launched - pass process start arguments from new process to a "main" process.

Comment: Could you be so kind and show us what you have programmed so far?

Comment: Yes. 
Google search for **C# inter process communication** https://www.google.co.in/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20inter%20process%20communication

Comment: For Windows Forms applications, the ApplicationFramework is available for such single instance applications - including the passing of command line arguments to a running instance.

Comment: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/maxim/2010/02/13/single-instance-application-manager/